# how to check if object is dragged in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, drag

How do I know if the object was dragged and the direction it was dragged
My objects are cars and they follow different paths, I wanna test if they dragged forward(the front of the car can be pointing any direction since its following different paths)

Answer (score 0):

So I imagine you're using a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. in your method for your selector you'll want to check if the (X, Y) coordinates are greater or lower than it's original point.

Here's a good starting point:

```
func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let point: CGPoint = recognizer.locationInView(self.view)
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .Changed:
            if let view = recognizer.view {
                carImageView.center = CGPoint(x: point.x, y: point.y)
            }
        case .Ended:
            if point.x > 0 {
                // went right
             } else {
                // went left
             }
             if point.y > 0 {
                 // went down
             } else {
                 // went up
             }
         default: break
         }
     }
}
```

You can do other cool things like setting up an Enum for the cases of: .Up, .Down, .Left, .Right and you can implement behaviors that way.

Comment: And how do I get the car direction? I need to compare the car direction with the drag direction - the car is following a random path

Comment: Thanks for helping... But I still can't see how I will compare the directions... I don't want to drag the car around... I want to speed up the car if it get dragged forward... Do you know if it's possible to compare somehow if the dragging is the same as the direction the car is going?

Comment: can the car only go forward or backwards on a 2d sidescrolling type of plane or is it a top down old school GTA type of view?

Comment: Its a 2d plane, but the car is following random CGPaths, so forward can be to the left to a car and to the right for another, at the same time. One car can be going to the left and other going to the right. I want them to go faster when dragged in the direction they are going.